# Hybridauth - Refresh token is always empty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hybridauth

I was using the Hybridauth 2.3.0 library with the CodeIgniter framework and I was encountering a problem.  My issue is that the refresh token is always empty.

**Hybrid\Provider_Model_OAuth2.php:**

```
function refreshToken()
{
    // have an access token?
    if( $this->api->access_token ){
    // have to refresh?
    //==> $this->api->refresh_token always return false (empty)

    if( $this->api->refresh_token && $this->api->access_token_expires_at ){
    // expired?
        if( $this->api->access_token_expires_at <= time() ){ 
            $response = $this->api->refreshToken( array("refresh_token" => $this->api->refresh_token ) );

            if( ! isset( $response->access_token ) || ! $response->access_token ){
                // set the user as disconnected at this point and throw an exception
                $this->setUserUnconnected();

                throw new Exception( "The Authorization Service has return an invalid response while requesting a new access token. " . (string) $response->error ); 
            }

            // set new access_token
            $this->api->access_token = $response->access_token;

            if( isset( $response->refresh_token ) ) 
                $this->api->refresh_token = $response->refresh_token; 

                if( isset( $response->expires_in ) ){
                    $this->api->access_token_expires_in = $response->expires_in;

                    // even given by some idp, we should calculate this
                    $this->api->access_token_expires_at = time() + $response->expires_in; 
                }
            }
        }

        // re store tokens
        $this->token( "access_token" , $this->api->access_token  );
        $this->token( "refresh_token", $this->api->refresh_token );
        $this->token( "expires_in"   , $this->api->access_token_expires_in );
        $this->token( "expires_at"   , $this->api->access_token_expires_at );
    }
}
```

that means when the access token expires, an exception is triggered at this time like this:

**Hybrid\Providers\Google.php:**

```
throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response.", 6 );
```

so the user must log out and log in again. 
What should I do to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to refresh the token, using Hybridauth 3?